# Python creating and traversing a simple menu

Tags: python

I am creating my first Python project. What I am working on is a simple text-based metric to standard (and vice versa) conversion program. I am not seeking the code as I want to figure this out myself. However, I am running into a problem traversing the menu. For example, there are 3 menus: main menu, metric menu, and standard menu. The program opens to the main menu. On the main menu the user can choose to navigate to the metric menu, standard menu, or to exit the program. If the user wants to be able to return to the main menu from the metric or standard menus, what would be the best approach? I have tried while loops and if/elif. However, it seems that my code gets really bloated and convoluted. Could someone please give me some advice on creating and traversing text menus in Python?

Comment: If each menu is handled by a separate function, then going back to the previous menu would just be a `return`.

Comment: Welcome to the world that is StackOverflow! I can't understand well your problem. Those menus are what? Prints? Or do they use some library?

Comment: Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import sys
import os

def switch():
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()
    s = 0
    while s != 5:
        s = int(input('1)Metric 2)Standard 3)Exit\n'))
        if s == 1:
            clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
            clear()
            metric()
        elif s == 2:
            clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
            clear()
            standard()
        elif s == 3:
            clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
            clear()
            exit()
        else:
            print('Out of range.')

def metric():
    '''Your code here'''
    s = int(input('0)Back\n'))
    if s == 0:
        switch()
    else:
        print('Out of range.')
    
def standard():
    '''Your code here'''
    s = int(input('0)Back\n'))
    if s == 0:
        switch()
    else:
        print('Out of range.')
    

switch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you were new to Python, the `__init__()` method of a class is called when the object is first constructed.  [You can read the docs on classes here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) (skip to 9.3).

I don't know how efficient this would be, but you could use a class that stores other objects of the same class:

```py
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, content, short_view, submenus = None):
        self.content = content
        self.short_view = short_view
        if submenus != None:
            self.choices = dict(enumerate(submenus, 1))
            for sub in submenus:
                sub.parent = self
        else:
            self.choices = {}


subsub1 = Menu("this is subsub1 content", "this goes to subsub1")
subsub2 = Menu("this is subsub2 content", "this goes to subsub2")
subsub3 = Menu("this is subsub3 content", "this goes to subsub3")

sub1 = Menu("this is the first sub menu content", "this goes to sub1", [subsub1, subsub2, subsub3])
sub2 = Menu("this is the second sub menu content", "this goes to sub2")

main = Menu("this is the main menu content", "this goes to main, but will never be used", [sub1, sub2])
main.parent = main

current_menu = main
while True:
    print(current_menu.content)
    print("\n".join([f"[{num}] {current_menu.choices[num].short_view}" for num in current_menu.choices]))
    inpt = input("Choice: ")
    if inpt == "exit":
        break
    elif inpt == "back":
        current_menu = current_menu.parent
    else:
        current_menu = current_menu.choices[int(inpt)]
```

Usage (in shell):

```
this is the main menu content
[1] this goes to sub1
[2] this goes to sub2
Choice: 1
this is the first sub menu content
[1] this goes to subsub1
[2] this goes to subsub2
[3] this goes to subsub3
Choice: back
this is the main menu content
[1] this goes to sub1
[2] this goes to sub2
Choice: exit
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code :

```
def main():
    a=int(input("1) metric\n2) standard\n3) exit\n"))
    if a==1:
        metric()
    elif a==2:
        standard()
    elif a==3:
        main()   #return main()
def metric():
    # your code
    pass
def standard():
    # your code
    pass
main()
```

Comment: I settled on something similar to that you posted. I actually got it working pretty well after all day pulling my hair out. It's one thing working through tutorials, and something completely different when it's just you and an IDE. Thank you!